# Re-load ViewController when app is resumed

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, view, uiviewcontroller

My app only has one `ViewController` and thus one `ViewController.swift`

I'd like for that `ViewController` to be re-loaded whenever the user resumes the app (multitasking). There is initialisation code in the `viewDidLoad()` function that does not fire when the app is resumed. I want this code to fire whenever the app is resumed and thus I would like to re-load the `ViewController` when the app is resumed.

Is there an elegant way to do this in Swift?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add and observer to your view controller to notify when your app enters foreground. Whenever your app enters foreground, this method `reloadView` will be called by the observer. Note that you will have to call this method yourself `self.reloadView()` when the view loads for the first time.

Here is the Swift code for this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.reloadView()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
     selector: "reloadView",
     name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification,
     object: nil)
}

func reloadView() {
    //do your initalisations here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go in your app delegate.m file

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
// This method gets called every time your app becomes active or in foreground state.
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"appisactive" object:nil];
}
```

Go to your view controller.m file and suppose you want to change the text of a label every time user comes back to the app from background to foreground.
By default the label of the text be something like this.

```
@implementation ViewController{
UIlabel *lbl;
}
-(void)viewDidLoad{
lbl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 75, 30)];
lbl.text = @"text1";
[self.view addSubview:lbl];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(textChange) name:@"appisactive" object:nil];
//this view controller is becoming a listener to the notification "appisactive" and will perform the method "textChange" whenever that notification is sent.
}
```

Finally

```
-(void)textChange{
lbl.text = @"txt change";
}
```

After implementing these run the project.
Command + H to go to make the app go into background without stopping it in Xcode.
Then press Command + H + H (2 times consecutively) and open the application, and you will notice the change in the text of the label.

This is just a demo to make you grasp the idea of notifications from the application delegate.

Comment: Thank you for this information. Is there a way to integrate this code into a swift project? Thanks again.

Answer (score -1):

you can do this in two different ways.

1.) There is a function in viewController `viewWillAppear` try to use the reload functionality in this function. It is called every time view appears.

2.) There  is a function in appDelegate `applicationWillEnterForeground` try to use the reload functionality in this function. It is called every time application become return from background mode.

I hope this would help .Thanks

Comment: `viewWillAppear` is not called when application enters foreground

Comment: View will appear dsnt gets called when app is back in foreground from background

Comment: applicationWillEnterForeground is also surprisingly not working. I'm using this:  func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
     println("Hello again world")

  
} and the function never fires which is odd